# I'm having issues in setting up my laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I got a new Laravel project but it showing the following error and it is not letting me run it using php artisan serve I tried using composer self-update too but it is not working....

> php artisan serve

Here's the error =>

```
PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 1349)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(576): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp...')#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()      
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManifest() 
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('aliases')
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->aliases()
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()   
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main} in C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php on line 11

In Collection.php line 11:

  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatib   
  le with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in   
   C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php:1349                                                              
  Stack trace:                                                                                                                                             
  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Collection.php(11): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handle   
  Error(8192, 'Return type of ...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 1349)
  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(576): include('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
  #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(427): Composer\Autoload\{closure}('C:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
  #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\helpers.php(110): Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Illuminate\\Supp   
  ...')
  #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(130): collect(Array)
  #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->build()    
  #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->getManife   
  st()
  #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest->config('a   
  liases')
  #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\Foundation\PackageManifest-   
  >aliases()
  #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades->bo   
  otstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
  #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWit   
  h(Array)
  #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap   
  ()
  #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\fitway\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony   
  \Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
  #13 {main}
```

Please tell me how can I resolve it.

I have tried changing the Php version in the .env file as well but it is not working either.

Chatgpt or Gemini have not been much of help either....

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6089612)

Comment: ok I removed it.

Comment: PHP 8.1.25 (cli) (built: Oct 25 2023 08:06:57) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.25, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies   @KenLee

Comment: What version of laravel are  you trying to use ?

Comment: If you are trying to create the project using composer then there should be no problem. If you haven't already, try to do so using composer.
`composer create-project laravel/laravel project_folder`

Comment: @Ismail I got this project from my senior so I had to import the db in the mysql server (xampp) I have not used -> composer create-project laravel/laravel project_folder while I  copied it....

Comment: @KenLee  How can i check it?  in the .env file there is no mention off which version  of laravel or php is being used.

Comment: Check the composer.json or check `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php` , see the VERSION

Comment: @KenLee  it is using version 7.3 => 
    const VERSION = '7.30.6';  in  the comments  it had this => The Laravel framework version.

Comment: [Laravel release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#support-policy) show that Laravel 7 is compatible with PHP versions between 7.2 - 8.0.  You have PHP 8.1.

Comment: I changed my php version now there are some errors with db connectivity &  migrations.... @Don'tPanic

Comment: @KenLee how can I fix this issue => Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fit\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Don'tPanic  I changed  my php version to 7.4.16 to match with the projects laravel ie 7.30.1

Comment: You're welcome ... ?! If you have a new question, I suggest closing this one since it is not likely to help future visitors, and asking a new question. But first, please do your research - there are thousands of questions here about Laravel database problems.

Comment: @Don'tPanic yeah I'm looking through them once I resolve the issue => Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fit\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;') in Unknown on line 0      I'll close this question.

Comment: @KenLee Ok I'll look through that documentation. Thanks for providing the link to me.

Comment: Now the thing which is bugging me most is that I don't have a server.php file in the directory but as  you guys can see in the error it is saying that it is missing that file.....                  Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\fit\server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR;') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Some antivirus will treat `server.php` as virus and **delete it**. So pls try disabling your antivirus and recover it from the quarantine pool

Comment: If you think this question will no longer help other people, then as suggested above by a commenter, you may delete this question by yourself. Otherwise (if you think it may help other people), then you can `answer your own question` (may need to wait for 1 day later ? I am not sure for your case... )  highlighting (1) the need to have compatible PHP version for laravel, and (2) disable antivirus in case server.php is deleted

Comment: @KenLee  sure I'll wait & answer my own question tomorrow with the highlighted insights &  close the question.